# How to see the comments on the tags in the NebulaGraph databse?

Tags: nebula-graph

I am using the basketballplayer dataset for testing, and added some comments on the player and team tag.

How can I show these comments?

I tried show tags but that doesn't work. Does Nebula Graph support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SHOW CREATE TAG player;
```

Ref: https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/3.ngql-guide/7.general-query-statements/6.show/5.show-create-tag-edge/